# Comparing two sets of equal width binned data

Tags: binning

I have two distinct sets of ~1500 intervals of differing lengths - let’s call them `Interval Set 1` and `Interval Set2`.

I have another set of data that contains values that fall within each of the sets of intervals - I’ll call it `Data Values`.

I want to compare the how the `Data Values` are distributed across `Interval Set 1` and `Interval Set 2` - Are the values generally higher or lower at the beginning or end of the intervals? Is there a difference in this distribution between `Interval Set 1` and `Interval Set 2`?

To approach this, I binned the intervals into 100 equal width bins (`% Interval`). I summed up the `Data Values` that fall within each bin for each interval set, generating two matrices of [100 bin values x ~1500 intervals]. I calculated the average `Data Value`/bin [100 averages] and plotted this against `% Interval` for each interval set.

This approach has shown me that there are differences in how the `Data Values` are distributed, and indeed, it appears that there are differences in this distribution between `Interval Set 1` and `Interval Set 2`.

However, I am having trouble directly comparing the results, primarily because the distribution of interval lengths is different between `Interval Set 1` and `Interval Set 2`. When plotted on the same graph, `Interval Set 1` averages are always much lower than those for `Interval Set2`, but I suspect it’s simply because of this difference in interval length.

`Interval Set 1` lengths have a mean of ~4000

`Interval Set 2` lengths have a mean of ~10000

So, in general, more of the `Data Values` are falling inside of the `% Interval` bins created for `Interval Set 2`. There are definitely some bins, particularly for `Interval Set 1`, where no `Data Values` fall inside, and the bin for that interval ends up with a value of 0. I suspect that I am ending up with lower averages for `Interval Set 1` simply because there are more bins that end up with 0 values.

Does anyone know of a better way that I can quantitatively compare the `Data Values` distributions between my two Interval sets? Do I just need to use smaller bins?